# Custom sorting an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a simple array that I would like to sort in the following way: Critical, Major, Moderate, Minor

```
Array
    (
        [Major] => 9
        [Critical] => 5
        [Moderate] => 6
        [Minor] => 5
    )
```

I am not sure how to go about custom sorting based on the key in PHP

Comment: Will the keys always be exactly those same words?

Comment: You mean to say that you have array with predefined sets of key and each key holds some numbers, you are looking for logic to sort that array based on Key order given by you. Correct me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.

```
$arr = ['Major' => 9, 'Critical' => 5, 'Moderate' => 6, 'Minor' => 3];
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $order = ['Critical' => 0, 'Major' => 1, 'Moderate' => 2, 'Minor' => 3];
    return $order[$a] - $order[$b];
}

uksort($arr, "cmp");
```

Live example here - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce8991112a01e020014520cafaf59d38da32c2ec

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.